# Indecomposable representations of an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $\rho$ be an indecomposable representation of Algebra A on a finite dimensional vector space V. Let $a \in Z(A)$, how do I show $\rho(a)$ has exactly one eigenvalue. $Z(A)$ represents the centre of algebra $A$. It is easy to see it has one eigenvalue, how do I show it is **exactly** one?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Lambda$ be the set of eigenvalues for $\rho(a)$ on $V$, and for $\lambda\in\Lambda$, define
$$V_\lambda=\{v\in V\mid (\rho(a)-\lambda)^Nv=0\mbox{ for }N\gg0\}.$$
Then, we have a vector space decomposition
$$V=\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\Lambda}V_\lambda.$$

[*proof:* We certainly have $V=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}V_\lambda$, so we only need to show it is direct. To this end, suppose $v\in V_\lambda\cap V_\mu$ is nonzero and $\lambda\neq\mu$. Choose $N$ such that $v':=(\rho(a)-\lambda)^Nv\neq 0$, but $(\rho(a)-\lambda)^{N+1}v=0$. Then, $\rho(a)v'=\lambda v'$.

Now, take $M> 0$, such that $(\rho(a)-\mu)^Mv=0$. Then,
\begin{align*}
0&=(\rho(a)-\lambda)^N(\rho(a)-\mu)^Mv\\
&=(\rho(a)-\mu)^M(\rho(a)-\lambda)^Nv\\
&=(\rho(a)-\mu)^Mv'\\
&=(\lambda-\mu)^Mv'\neq0
\end{align*}
because $\lambda\neq\mu$. This is a contradiction.]

In fact, we claim that for $\lambda\in\Lambda$, $V_\lambda$ is an $A$-submodule. Indeed, suppose $x\in A$, and $v\in V_\lambda$. Then, there exists $N\gg0$ such that $(\rho(a)-\lambda)^Nv=0$. But, now 
$$
(\rho(a)-\lambda)^Nxv=x(\rho(a)-\lambda)^Nv=0
$$
so $xv\in V_\lambda$ as required.

Finally, we conclude that $|\Lambda|=1$ since $V$ is indecomposable.

Comment: Why do we have $V=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}V_\lambda$

Comment: @Mohan I'm assuming you are working over an algebraically closed field. Anyway, its sort of silly for me to put a proof of this fact. Look, just choose a basis for $V$ so that in this basis $\rho(a)$ is in Jordan normal form.

Comment: @Mohan To prove this the way I started, proceed by induction on $V$. If $\dim V=1$, the statement is obvious. Now, if $\sum V_\lambda\neq V$, then since $\sum V_\lambda$ is an $a$-submodule, we can let $a$ act on $X=V/\sum V_\lambda$ which has strictly smaller dimension than $V$. (Along the way, you are using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to show that $\Lambda\neq\emptyset$.) Now $X$ has a generalized eigenspace decomposition, which allows us to enlarge $\Lambda$. The details are a bit tedious.